# Simplify php curl code

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to get a JSON from a url. My code is working but I think that I could do it better. (remove json_decode or json_encode). Right now this is what I have: (EDIT: I still want to use curl)

```
<?php
 $curl = curl_init('url');

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'url');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $result = curl_exec($curl);

 curl_close($curl);

 $data = json_decode($result, true);

 echo json_encode($data["name"]);

 ?>
```

Comment: You can use the file_get_contents function instead of all the curl functions

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($data);
```